# Building up a QString pointer for the following?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the easiest way to build up this string?
(I know I can go about a long way with char casting etc... prefer to stay within the context of QString)  thx

```
m_qstr = (m_qstr->toStdString() + "\r\n\r\n" + qstrResults.toStdString()  + "\r\n");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `m_qstr` is a QString pointer and you are trying to assign it an `std::string`.  First you will need to dereference your pointer so you get the object, then you can convert the std::string to a char* using c_str() so your QString can copy it:

```
*m_qstr = (m_qstr->toStdString() + "\r\n\r\n" + qstrResults.toStdString()  + "\r\n").c_str();
```

Another way, and probably the better way is to not convert everything to `std::string` and just keep the QStrings:

```
*m_qstr = *m_qstr + "\r\n\r\n" + qstrResults + "\r\n";
```

Comment: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'QString*' in assignment

Comment: Did you use `*m_qstr = ` or just `m_qstr =`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [QString append](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html).

```
(*m_qstr).append("\r\n\r\n").append(qstrResults).append("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `toStdString`? If m_qstr is a `QString`, you should have no problems with concatenating `QString` and `const char*`. I use this method all of the time with my Qt applications:

```
QString str = "Testing";
str += " concatenation.";
```